# How to install custom pakages on Google-Colaboratory

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to install packages on GOOGLE COLAB, but I'm facing Import error, I can't import Sub module of my main module 'gym'.

[image]

I done the following things.

First I cloned the git hub repository through git command (! git clone https://github.com/zoraiz-ali/gym.git)

Then I add the directory using sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gym')
```

Code of my setup.py file is given below

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
     name="gym_robot",
     version="0.3",
     url="https://github.com/zoraiz-ali/gym.git",
     author="Zoraiz Ali",
     license="MIT",
     packages=["gym_robot", "gym_robot.envs", "gym_robot.envs.helper", ],
     include_package_data=True,
     install_requires=["gym", "numpy", "opencv-python", "pillow"]
)
```

The package works very well on my computer/s. So I'm not sure why I'm not able to use it on Colaboratory.

Anyone know the solution please check this.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733786/how-to-import-custom-modules-in-google-colab

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is caused by the fact that your module has the same name as another package, which is the [`gym`](https://pypi.org/project/gym/) package for reinforcement learning environments. This package is automatically installed in the google colab environment, so when you try to import `gym_robot`  from `gym` it assumes you want to import it from the existing package instead of your own module. Since the package doesn't have this function/module it will give an import error. Try changing the name of your own module slightly so it doesn't interfere with the existing `gym` package.

Answer (score 0):

Include a pip install command at the beginning of your notebook. Check one of the notebooks here, for example: https://github.com/arangodb/interactive_tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/Graph_Retail_DA_I.ipynb